# No Integration defined for method error message: x-amazon-apigateway-integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using the the [AWS API Gateway importer](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer) and I am running the following command to update an existing API:

```
./aws-api-import.cmd --update API-ID --deploy TEST_STAGE /yourImporterInstallation/tst/resources/swagger/uber.yaml
```

However, I am returned with the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.apigateway.model.BadRequestException: No integration defined for method  (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: null; Request ID: ID)
```

I have found out that the sample json (I am using uber.json from /tst/resources/swagger) does not include the `"x-amazon-apigateway-integration"`, but I am not sure how to add it. What is the command? Can you point me to the right resource? My final goal is to find a ways for systematically importing, updating, deleting and deploying an API on AWS.

Thank you

**EDIT & ANSWER:**

So, I have resolved the issue by adding a Mock Type for the Integration Method (it could have been a Lambda or HTTP, it is just to get it working first)

```
aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id API-ID --resource-id RESOURCE-ID --http-method GET --type MOCK --request-templates '{ "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}" }' --region us-east-1
```

Then I can successfully run:

```
./aws-api-import.cmd --update API-ID --deploy TEST_STAGE /yourImporterInstallation/tst/resources/swagger/uber.yaml
```

However, I have multiple endpoints and GET methods, so I am looking for a command that would allow me to add the same Integration Method to multiple or even all Methods. Can you help?

Thank you

Comment: How about including the content of your yaml file in the question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the content of my yaml file is from:  https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer/blob/master/tst/resources/swagger/uber.yaml

Comment: Just FYI, that tool is not supported now. It has been replaced by an import API within the service: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/create-api-using-import-export-api.html

Comment: @Jack Kohn -AWS, thanks for your reply. I am looking at the best approach for automating the creation, update and deletion of APIs (my final intent is to put in place some CD with CodeDeploy) and I was under the impression that the Swagger importer was the way to go. Are you suggesting to use the API Gateway Rest API? Do you have any interesting resource on how to use it in CodeDeploy?

Comment: I don't have anything related to CodeDeploy, but the API I mentioned above is supported in the CLI and all of the SDKs. CLI -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/import-rest-api.html or http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/put-rest-api.html

Comment: Thanks again, appreciated. Yeah, I have been playing with the Import/Export API and yes the Delete API does the job. My question is are you planning to have a Bulk API for importing, updating, deploying operations? Can you actually use the current API in a more Bulk/Batch fashion?

Comment: I've just had this error ("An error occurred: ApiGatewayDeployment153xxxxx - No integration defined for method (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: xxxxx).") while deploying a Lambda + API Gateway service with Serverless. It turned out to be, apparently, a temporary issue on AWS's side, as after retrying a few times (without changing anything) it eventually worked as it used to.